# Make datetimepicker working with editable-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am using two wonderful jQuery plugins for a project:

- this date/time picker: https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker
- this HTML table editor: https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table

They work separately very well but unfortunately they are not compatible for each other. When I want to update a date in a HTML table, the calendar appears and closes when I click on the date/time, but the value in the table's cell is not updated (and Chrome's javascript console does not report any error message). Would you know a solution or a workaround for that ? You can quickly test it by yourself with the code below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en' dir='ltr'>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='http://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/mindmup-editabletable.js'></script>
        <link href='http://xdsoft.net/scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <script src='http://xdsoft.net/scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('table').editableTableWidget();
                $('.picker').datetimepicker({ format:'Y-m-d H:i' });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The date/time picker works perfectly:</p>
        <input class='picker' />
        </br></br>
        <p>But not in the table below:</p>
        <table style='border:1px solid black'>
            <tr><td class='picker'>2014-08-22 15:00</td></tr>
            <tr><td>However no problem for text, i.e. just here!</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It would be awesome that these two plugins could work together. Thanks!

Pierre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your question when I was looking for something that would do what you were looking to do. I didn't find it, so modified the mindmup solution, expanding it to include a couple of different editing methods. The ones I ended up with are:

- Regular text.
- Date, using bootstrap-datepicker.
- Value text, which is something specific for my application, where the user can enter a whole number with or without commas and have them displayed with commas.
- Numbers, being whole numbers using the `<input type="number">` element.
- Selects. These are a bit more tricky, but essentially you provide a javascript associative array, and the code uses the `data-edit-source` attribute to find the array.

There is an example on the [git repository](https://github.com/oti169/editable-table). I'd put the code in here, but I'm lazy, and don't want to explain it. Sorry about that. If you download the code, there is a demo in the index.html file.

The table looks like this:

```
<table id="secondDemo" class="table table-striped">
  <thead><tr>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Expires</th>
    <th>Count</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-edit-type="select" data-edit-source="locations">Adelaide</td>
      <td data-edit-type="date">24-Jan-2015</td>
      <td data-edit-type="ntext">8</td>
      <td data-edit-type="vtext">5,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-edit-type="select" data-edit-source="locations">Brisbane</td>
      <td data-edit-type="date">25-Jan-2015</td>
      <td data-edit-type="ntext">8</td>
      <td data-edit-type="vtext">15,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-edit-type="select" data-edit-source="locations">Melbourne</td>
      <td data-edit-type="date">26-Jan-2015</td>
      <td data-edit-type="ntext">9</td>
      <td data-edit-type="vtext">8,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-edit-type="select" data-edit-source="locations">Sydney</td>
      <td data-edit-type="date">27-Jan-2015</td>
      <td data-edit-type="ntext">6</td>
      <td data-edit-type="vtext">9,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

... and the required javascript looks like this:

```
var locations = {
    'Adelaide': 'Adelaide - South Australia',
    'Brisbane': 'Brisbane - Queensland',
    'Canberra': 'Canberra - Australian Capital Territory',
    'Darwin': 'Darwin - Northern Territory',
    'Hobart': 'Hobart - Tasmania',
    'Melbourne': 'Melbourne - Victoria',
    'Perth': 'Perth - Western Australia',
    'Sydney': 'Sydney - New South Wales'
};
$('#secondDemo').editableTableWidget();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The editable table widget creates new `<input/>`'s that are hidden and appear whenever a user clicks on the field. In order for datetimepicker to work on those fields, you have to tell editable table to add the `picker` class to the inputs:

```
$(function() {
    $('table').editableTableWidget({editor: $('<input class="picker"/>')});
    $('.picker').datetimepicker({ format:'Y-m-d H:i' });
});
```

[DEMO Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ztrxebg/)

Edit: I just realized that this won't work in the way you want. Looking at the code, editable table only creates 1 hidden input box that it uses for all table cells. Thus, this will only work if you want all of your table cells to be datepickers.

Comment: Dear both, thanks a lot for your feedback. Ok I see origin of the problem, I will try to find a table editor which is able to handle several classed for input.

Answer (score 0):

As kind of workaround I just adjusted your Fiddle like that: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/uf2Lhd40/)

with following changes:

```
$(function () {
  $('table').editableTableWidget();
  $('.picker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i'
  });
  $('.pickertwo').datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i'
   });
   $(".pickertwo").on("change", function () {
    var textVal = $(this).val();
    $(".textpick").text(textVal);
   });
   $(".pickTwo").on("click", function () {
    $(".pickertwo").focus();
   })
});
```

Markup changes:

```
<input class='picker' /> 
<table style='border:1px solid black' class="pickTwo">
<tr>
    <td class='textpick'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>However no problem for text, i.e. just here!</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input class='pickertwo' />
```

Problem is to hide the 2nd datepicker - setting `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` will disable the functionality. Maybe it's possible that you set a low `z-index` value for the 2nd input and hide it behind an image that matches the page where you would implement it and set a higher `z-index` for this image.